# authentication using ember-simple-auth-devise and rails backend

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I am trying to implement a authentication system in ember with the following versions:

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
ember.debug.js:5378 DEBUG: Ember                    : 1.13.7
ember.debug.js:5378 DEBUG: Ember Data               : 1.13.8
ember.debug.js:5378 DEBUG: jQuery                   : 1.11.3
ember.debug.js:5378 DEBUG: Ember Simple Auth        : 0.8.0
ember.debug.js:5378 DEBUG: Ember Simple Auth Devise : 0.8.0
ember.debug.js:5378 DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

I followed the instructions on github for https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/tree/master/packages/ember-simple-auth-devise

Now when I hit 'sign up' it is returning a 500 error:

```
POST http://localhost:4200/users/sign_in 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I feel like it should be going to localhost:3000/users/sign_in, but it isn't.

I launched the server with `ember s --proxy http://localhost:3000` command, but don't understand whats happening.

Here is my code for reference:

controller/login.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import LoginControllerMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/login-controller-mixin';

export default Ember.Controller.extend(LoginControllerMixin, {
  authenticator: 'simple-auth-authenticator:devise'
});
```

routes/login.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import UnauthenticatedRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/unauthenticated-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(UnauthenticatedRouteMixin);
```

templates/application.hbs

```
<h2 id="title">Welcome to Ember.js - With Authentication!</h2>

{{#if session.isAuthenticated}}
    Hi, {{session.email}}
    <br/>
    You can't see this text unless you're logged in!
    <br/>
    Click this button to logout:
    <button {{action 'invalidateSession'}}>Logout</button>
    <br/>
    If you try to go to the
    {{#link-to "login"}}Login{{/link-to}}
    page, you should get redirected!
{{else}}
  {{#link-to "login"}}Login{{/link-to}}
{{/if}}

{{outlet}}
```

templates/login.hbs

```
<form {{action "authenticate" on="submit"}}>
    <div>
        <label for="identification">E-mail</label><br />
      {{input value=identification placeholder="E-mail" type="text" name="email"}}
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="password">Password</label><br />
      {{input value=password placeholder="Password" type="password" name="password"}}
    </div>

    <div>
        <button type="submit">Log in</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

config/environment.js

```
...
  ENV['simple-auth'] = {
    authorizer: 'simple-auth-authorizer:devise'
  }

  ENV['simple-auth-devise'] = {
    tokenAttributeName: 'token',
    identificationAttributeName: 'email'
  }
...
```

My rails routes looks like:

```
  devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'sessions' }
```

Comment: does the request ever reach the Rails backend?

Comment: yes, it returns, `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/users/sign_in"):` (added my devise routes in above)

Comment: That means the `/users/sign_in` route isn't configured in the Rails app, this the 500 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your routes.rb file you might need adding **at: 'users'** as the default route provided by devise for sign_in is http://ip_address_to_your_server/sign_in and to create your custom url like http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in you have to map it on 'users'. The resulting code would look like

```
devise_for :users, at 'users',controllers: { sessions: 'sessions' }
```

This way you will be able to call the SessionsController at /users

Hope this helps. Otherwise please consider posting the code implemented at your rails backend because the problem is at Rails end.